# Whiteboard Making

Tags: android

Hy!!
I want to make a Whiteboard app, but i don't know how to make only some pixels black and let the others white.

Comment: This is a big question, can you narrow it down a bit. How far have you got so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: You just need to market it correctly. **Whiteboard Lite** *(board marker not included)*

Comment: no i want to programm it my own...
I want to identify each pixel of the display and when it was pressed it should change the color... sorry i have a bad english

Answer (score 5):

This should help getting black pixels on your whiteboard:

Scribbler.java:

```
package org.yourpackage.scribble;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Scribbler extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);
        drawView.requestFocus();
        
    }
}
```

DrawView.java:

```
package org.yourpackage.scribble;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Point point : points) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 2, paint);  
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = event.getX();
        point.y = event.getY();
        points.add(point);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

class Point {
    float x, y;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.yourpackage.scribble"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".Scribbler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

...which turns out to look like:

[image]

You may want to draw lines instead of pixels - this one is just to give you a clue

Comment: PERFEKT!!!

But what i don't understand is, why does the new View know that the paint is "on" it?

Comment: because in the Scribbler activity we set the our DrawView as the active content - and if there happens something on this DrawView we  get the coordinates within the onTouch method and then cause a the onDraw method to be called which draws our pixels - onDraw is called automatically because we force a re-draw of the View by calling invaldidate() within the onTouch - you can get information about this behaviour in the "Drawing" section of this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: +1 DonGru. using 2 for radius is too small when I used on my Nexus 7, so I'm using 20 on canvas.drawCircle() instead

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.
https://web.archive.org/web/20200223052828/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html

In addition you might also want a web application / service in order to transfer the screen contents to your audience.

Comment: like that?

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        
        canvas.drawPoint(20, 20, paint);
        
        
    }

but what about the view...

Comment: Please read this part on the link I posted to you.

"To do this:
Copy the whole code from droidnova the replace the following."

Comment: Do you know how the view know that the paint and the convas are on them?