# Whiteboard on android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a whiteboard in android. i am using the example suggested in  here - [Whiteboard Making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608455/whiteboard-making)

but this gives me everything in a dotted line. I want it to appear like a normal writing on a board. How can that be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the canvas drawing routine, use lineTo instead of drawCircle.

Comment: I used drawPath instead. Thanks buddy

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. I've not yet looked at the android sdk. I *have* made a drawing program before. So I couldn't be more specific due to my own ignorance of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the radius of circle to higher values

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Point point : points) {
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 50, paint); //Here radius is 50 
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = event.getX();
    point.y = event.getY();
    points.add(point);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```